# Django unicode conversion

Tags: python, django, unicode

I did some research on Unicode strings, but I've unfortunately not been able to figure out why Python does some things.

I have this piece of code:

```
output["anything"] = {
    "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "somename",
            "amenity": "Store",
            "popupContent": "Store 3 "
        },
     }
```

When I use `print(output)` it prints this as:

```
{u'anything': u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'amenity': u'Store', u'name': u'somename', u'popupContent': u'Store 3'}}
```

I would however like to have this without the `u' '` as my javascript utility won't read this.

Comment: "I would however like to have this without the `u' '` as my javascript utility won't read this." - if you want to dump JSON, use a JSON dumper, not `print`. `print` is not intended to be JSON-compatible.

Comment: If you actually have that piece of code, `output` wouldn't print that way, since none of those strings are Unicode.  What do you really have?  Make a [mcve].  The `json` module what you need, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `json.dumps` instead of print.

```
import json

output = {}
output["anything"] = {
    "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "somename",
            "amenity": "Store",
            "popupContent": "Store 3 "
        },
     }
print(json.dumps(output))
```

Output:

```
{"anything": {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "somename", "amenity": "Store", "popupContent": "Store 3 "}}}
```